# Imprimir mais de uma cópia em javascript

Tags: javascript

Eu consigo fazer uma impressão sair automaticamente em 3 cópias? Igual nessa janela abaixo.

```
window.onload = function() {
    window.print();
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Não, isso não é possível.**

Mas você pode ver isso como uma coisa boa.

Imagine se fosse possível e você acidentalmente ou um site mal intencionado enviasse um parâmetro para imprimir um número muito alto de páginas e um usuário desavisado clicasse em OK para imprimir sem notar na quantidade.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a documentação do [`window.print()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/print) não há parâmetro adicional para esta função. Logo, não é possível enviar mais cópias. Uma solução (que não é muito legal) é você chamar 3 vezes o método:

```
window.onload = function() {
  window.print();
  window.print();
  window.print();
}
```